# Automation on windows 10, using IE Edge and excel

Tags: javascript, automation, node.js

First time poster over here.

I have a project that I wish to carry out. I need the following to happen and I am unsure of what software/programming langues I should use to achieve what I need.

1. Open Excel
2. Refresh Data Connections to get data from database.
3. Save file again as .CSV
4. Open/Login HTML page to a page
5. Import the updated .csv file to another website.

I have thought about having 2 automatic cycles. One that Keeps the excel file open and run a VBA script to refresh the data connection every X hours.

Then another script possibly on VBA to load up the website and import the file, manipulating the DOM do this.

My main problem with this is interacting with the Windows pop ups when step 5 asks me to find the file ect... I think this is achievable however after reading up for a while I am not 100% it is?

I have thought about using Node.js (puppertier) to maniuplate the DOM however i think i will come across the same problem when the import windows pop up comes up.

So question really is, what do people recommend to use to achieve the above? I have been looking around for a while now and I cannot find anything along these lines yet. all I need is the place to look and I will be well underway!

Comment: For 4 & 5, look at Selenium. For 1,2,3 either Use Python or Autoit to drive Excel, or by pass Excel & access the database directly.

Comment: @Mawg thanks for advice, will take look at Selenium, I did wonder about using VBA all the way? As I was typing I could get all the way to step 5 and struggle, as manipulating the windows UI is possible but rather difficult! Gonna have a busy day now!

Comment: It has been along time since I used VBA, but it was made for that sort of thing, so ought to be ok. If you ever want to automate non-MS Office apps in Windows, you simply cannot beat AutoIt, so keep it in mind for future projects. Selenium is the industry standard for testing browser apps & VBA can't handle that, so it looks like two tools. Good luck :-)